Quick questions about ring isomorphisms.
Background
Example: Describe (briefly) the ring structure of the following rings:
$(a)$ $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2)$.
$(b)$ $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x)$.
$(c)$ $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$.
Edit:  From the comments, I understand what $(a), (b)$ are supposed to be, I am still not clear as to what $(c)$ is supposed to be isomorphic to.
I am self learning abstract algebra mainly from Hungerford's undergraduate abstract algebra text.  When I look at similar level algebra text and their quotient ring isomorphism exercises, especially practical/computational ones similar to the above three quoted ones, for some reasons I am having trouble figuring out what the isomorphisms are.  Is one thing to construct coset elements table, but another to figure out what the table is isomorphic to which other mathematical object.
Question
For the above three questions, I know that for $(a)$, $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2)\cong \Bbb{Z}_2$, for $(b)$, $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x)\cong \Bbb{Z}$. For $(c)$, i know that $(2x)\subset (2)\cap(x)$, so I can't really conclude that $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2x)\cong\Bbb{Z}[x]/((2)\cap(x))$, as a result I can't simply use the Chinese remainder theorem here, and hence I would not know what $\Bbb{Z}[x]/((2)\cap(x))$ would be isomorphic to.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

(In the following, $0 \in \Bbb{N}$.)
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{Z}[x] &= \left\{\sum_{i=0}^n z_i x^i \mid n \in \Bbb{N}, z_0,\dots,z_n \in \Bbb{Z}\right\}  \text{,}  \\
\langle 2 \rangle = 2\Bbb{Z}[x] &= \left\{\sum_{i=0}^n 2z_i x^i \mid n \in \Bbb{N}, z_0,\dots,z_n \in \Bbb{Z}\right\}  \text{,}  \\
\langle x \rangle = x\Bbb{Z}[x] &= \left\{\sum_{i=0}^n z_i x^{i+1} \mid n \in \Bbb{N}, z_0,\dots,z_n \in \Bbb{Z}\right\}  \\
    &= \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n z_i x^{i} \mid n \in \Bbb{N}, z_1,\dots,z_n \in \Bbb{Z}\right\}  \text{, and }  \\
\langle 2 x \rangle = 2x\Bbb{Z}[x] &= \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n 2z_i x^i \mid n \in \Bbb{N}, z_1,\dots,z_n \in \Bbb{Z} \right\}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Since $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is the set of $\Bbb{Z}$-linear combinations of finitely many (distinct) powers of $x$, it can be useful to think about what the quotients do to generic monomials.

Consider $z_i x^i$ modulo $\langle 2 \rangle$.  If $z_i$ is even, this term is sent to $0$ and if $z_i$ is odd, this term is sent to $x^i$.  That is, the coefficients are sent to their remainders modulo $2$.
Consider $z_i x^i$ modulo $\langle x \rangle$.  This sends every power of $x$ to zero.  So $z_0 x^0 \mapsto z_0$ and every other monomial is sent to zero.
Consider $z_i x^i$ modulo $\langle 2x \rangle$.  Every $\{r(2x) \mid r \in \Bbb{Z}[x]\}$ has degree greater than zero, so the constant coefficient is unaffected: $z_0 x^0 \mapsto z_0$.  $\{r(2x)\mid r \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ gives all the degree one monomials in $\langle 2x \rangle$, so we reduce the linear coefficient modulo $2$ and similarly, $\{r(2x) \mid r \in x^{i-1}\Bbb{Z}\}$ gives all the degree $i$ monomials in $\langle 2x \rangle$, so all the non-constant term coefficients are reduced modulo $2$.

Consequently,

$\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2 \rangle$ is

 $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})[x]$, polynomials in $x$ with coefficients $0,1 \in \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$,


$\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x \rangle$ is

 $\Bbb{Z}$,


$\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2x \rangle$ is

 $\displaystyle \left\{ z_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n z_i x^i \mid n \in \Bbb{N}, z_0 \in \Bbb{Z}, z_1,\dots,z_n \in \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z} \right\}$, polynomials in $x$ with arbitrary integral constant coefficient and with non-constant term coefficients $0,1 \in \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.




thank you for your detail write up and explanations.  My apologizes for replying so late.  I am still recovering from the flu.  To answer your earlier question from your comment:  Can you expilcitly write down a generic element of $\langle 2 \rangle \cap \langle x \rangle$? I.e. $\langle 2 \rangle \cap \langle x \rangle = {\text{(some form)} \mid \text{(some condition(s))} } \text{.}$  I think in terms of set builder notation, $\langle 2 \rangle \cap \langle x \rangle = {y\mid y=2\cdot p(x) \text{ and } y=x\cdot g(x), p(x), g(x)\in \Bbb{Z}[x]}$.  I made a minor mistake...

....according to an exercsie in Gallian's algebra text, in order for $\langle wv \rangle =\langle w \rangle\cap \langle v \rangle$ to hold true, where both $\langle w \rangle$ and $\langle v \rangle$ are ideals of commutative ring $R$ It is necessary that $\langle w \rangle+\langle v \rangle=R$, otherwise  $\langle wv \rangle \subset \langle w \rangle\cap \langle v \rangle$.

@Seth : Alrighty.  I can remove the one reference to the intersection.  (It's not critical.)

in these questions where the author asks the reader about describing the ring structure of a quotient ring, does she usually mean to show what the quotient rings are isomorphic to, along with what a typical coset elemeents look like? I mean what would an acceptable answer look like, or rather what is consider a complete answer to such a question.

@Seth : This would be an excellent question for your instructor (if you have one).  For a "first abstract algebra course", I'd accept either the set or the text in the "spoiler blocks" above.  For a later abstract algebra course, I'd expect the text.  "Describe (briefly) the ring structure of ..." wants a description that another student in your class (or self-studying the same material) can quickly understand.  "Polynomials in $x$ with the following degree (or coefficient) restrictions: ..." is an example.  <continued ...>

@Seth <continuing...>  It is rare that there is a terse description of what the quotient is isomorphic to -- and it's not clear that such a description is useful.  One would like to express elements of a quotient as a subset of elements of the starting ring, not as structurally dissimilar elements of some other (isomorphic) ring.  Being able to identify a typical coset element is seldom the most useful characterization.  Being able to tersely describe a collection of representatives, one from each coset, is much more useful.

if I am ask to describe the ring structure of $R/A$, where $A$ is an ideal of $R$, then it would be enough if I can write out in set builder notation what the set of equivalence classes look like, give the list of coset elements in the quotient ring $R/A$,, the construction of the multiplication table in terms of their coset elements, and if possible give the evaluation hmomorphic map $phi:R\to S$ is and using the first isomorphism theorem to show $R/A\cong ??$

@Seth : This is vastly too much for "Describe (briefly) the ring structure of ...".  The multiplication and addition tables should be obvious, since they are inherited from $R$.  And I'm concerned about your frequent use of "coset elements" -- these are obtained from any element, $r \in R$ as $rA$ -- much more useful is a set of representatives.  Compare/contrast $\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$: one way (not the best way) to write the three cosets are $3\Bbb{Z}+0$, $3\Bbb{Z}+4$, and $3\Bbb{Z}-4$ but what you compute with are "$0$", "$1$", and "$2$", one representative from each coset.

Also, if one wishes to communicate clearly, is it of any use to say $\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle 2x \rangle \cong \Bbb{Z} \oplus (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})[x]$ or is it more useful to say it is the set of polynomials in $x$ with unconstrained integer constant coefficient and all other coefficients from $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$?  Remember that you are writing to communicate to humans.  Notation affords precision but is not, by itself, an explanation.

sorry I meant representative elements of the set of coset.  I have seen these types of questions being asked in two different algebra textbooks.  One of them being Keith Nicholson's text.  The other thing is what if one does not know what the quotient ring is isomorphic to?  Should this last mathematical issue matter in the answer?  My understanding is people quotients put stuff from some mathematical objects, and from those quotiented out elements, they want to know what they are isomorphic to.

@Seth : If someone asks something like "Let $R$ be ... and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that ... Express $R/I$ without a quotient." then find a representative of the isomorphism class of the quotient.  Quotients are usually a technique to "mash together" objects whose difference(s) are (momentarily) irrelevant -- usually because the thing one wants to know about is whether two things are relevantly different or the same, or because computing with representatives is easier, preserving the differences that (momentarily) matter.  <continued...>

@Seth: What a textbook author wants to know is: are you actually collapsing an ideal's cosets into single representatives correctly.

ah okay okay.  I am always anxious about whenever I encounter anything quotient related, especially when it comes to having to figuring out what they are either isomorphic to or homeomorphic to.

For $k \in [2,10^8]$:


all sequences end at primes;


$k=98,112,697$ gives the greatest number of iterations, $305$;


$\max g = {}$ $g(55,245,322) = {}$ $g(61,241,178) = {}$ $g(82,867,982) = {}$ $g(90,768,174) = {}$ $g(91,861,766) = 4,396,502,880,258,324,850,443,328,819$.


